# Issues with Updating EF 4 Proc in Model Browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm having issues with updating a select stored procedure in the model browser.  Deleting the function import and proc isn't updating the object correctly.  What's happening is that when I remap it, it says the function returns no columns.  I execute it in SQL, and it returns data with the associated columns just fine.

I don't understand why EF is having problems; I was able to map originally the correct way.  When deleting the complex object

Found this similar issue, but I am not using dynamic SQL.  I am using a function though: [Entity Framework 4: The selected stored procedure returns no columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473998/entity-framework-4-the-selected-stored-procedure-returns-no-columns)

Any ideas?

Comment: I had this problem before too. If i remember correctly, i just re-created the SP under another name, then imported that, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are allowing the entity modeler to generate the complex type for you based on the results of the stored procedure.  In your stored procedure, try adding `SET FMTONLY OFF` before you do the final select of your result set.  Then, at the end of the procedure, `SET FMTONLY ON`.  You can remove both statements once the entity modeler has generated your complex type.  More information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583933/creating-entities-from-stored-procedures-which-have-dynamic-sql/3583971#3583971).