# map stored procedure to entity returning temproray table data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a stored procedure that returns the temporary table data. because i have used dynamic queries. When i tried to map stored procedure using complex types it returns no columns

how to handle temporary table columns name in complex types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported by default because EF always executes `SET FMTONLY ON` before executing your stored procedure. This option will turn off logic execution - it will only ask for metadata but if logic execution is turned off no temporary table is created and no column's metadata exists.

There are [some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997033/entity-framework-cant-handle-a-simple-table-variable).