# sp_executesql in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I created a stored procedure in the SQL Server database. Since it will search from a different table according to the entered value, it searches for that table name according to the variable and scans it with the sp_executesql query. There is no problem when you press f5 when you call the query in the database, but on the C# by web MVC project side, it does not show the result value of this query in the database connection because it is dynamic, not like a table.

What can I do against this?

I was expecting the query to reflect the result value and table content like other select-style queries, but it did not happen. In the MVC project, this procedure is not seen in the database model.

Example query;

```sql
set @sql ='select c.ABC,k.DEF, k.GHI  from tables.dbo.['+@value+'] k
join table_clients c on c.VALUE=k.VALUE where bla bla bla'
```

C# project code;

```cs
public requestsEntities database = new requestsEntities();
 
var result = database.procedureName(inputValue1,inputValue2).ToList();
```

Comment: Please try to [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: are you using entity framework? if so, which one, ef core or the ef6? how did you call the stored procedure from your [tag:asp.net-mvc] application?

Comment: @Bagus Tesa yes. entitiy framework and entitiy data model for ip-server name connection. Call stored procedure

Comment: is it code first or database first? the answer on "how to call stored procedure" depends on the approach that you had use. for database first for example, you can simply [update the `edmx` data model to add it into the model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43821598). however, [code first will require you to write the methods yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231306).

Comment: This kind of dynamic SQL is always a code smell to me. If you have a number of tables that are easily substituted (i.e. same columns) then it's often a design issue and these should be a single table with a column to determine different sets. I'd always advise against this approach, as I say when it is a requirement it is usually a false requirement as a result of a design issue, but if you must do this at the very least santise your input by checking the table exists before executing, what if `@value` happens to be `x]; DROP TABLE table_clients;--`.

Comment: You may find this kind of generic query would be much better handled in EF rather than in the database, but hard to say exactly how without further information on why you need this at all, and where your input values come from

Comment: even just a parameterised query would help, I doubt anyone will want to help you with the code in this state

Comment: What is the return type for the generated `database.procedureName()` function. Typically, it will be a class named `procedureName_Result` having properties matching the expected stored procedure results - in this case `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`. If that is not the case, it may be that case that when that procedure call was added to the EDMX, EF was not able to properly identify the return type. Try temporarily replacing the stored procedure with one having a fixed query like `SELECT ABC, DEF, GHI FROM SomeTable`, refresh the procedure in EDMX and check the generated result type again.

Comment: Side note: Your dynamic SQL would be slightly safer if you used the `QUOTENAME()` to inject table names or similar. Suggest replacing `... from tables.dbo.['+@value+'] k ...` with `... from tables.dbo.'+QUOTENAME(@value)+' k ...`.